# A delightful exercise in basic differentiation theory.

Tags: real-analysis

Here is a fun exercise for people who like real analysis.

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Suppose that $f$ has a local maximum at some point $c\in (a,b)$. Does there necessarily exist a small $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is decreasing $[c,c+\delta)$?

Before answering, try to visualize the situation!

Here is an answer in case you get stuck:

> The answer to the above question is actually no! The function $f(x)=x^2\sin^2(1/x)$ with $f(0)=0$
>  is differentiable at $0$, has a local max at $0$ and yet in no neighborhood $[0,\delta)$ is $f$ increasing or decreasing.

Now here is ***a more difficult question***. It is hidden because it contains spoilers to the above question.

> Let $c\in(a,b)$ be a local maximum of $f$ such that in no neighbourhood $[c,c+\delta)$ is $f$ increasing or decreasing. Can there be infinitely many such points $c$ in (a,b)?

It would be great if one would write an answer to the second question. I hope you enjoy these as much as I did!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't actually a question.  This might belong on puzzling.stackexchange.com but not here since it does not ask for answers, it poses a puzzle.

Comment: @postmortes is it possible to migrate the question to the puzzling forum?

Comment: I think you can copy it over by hand and then delete it here (you have no answers yet so I think you can do that).  Otherwise you will need to ask a moderator I think.

Comment: @postmortes even though I asked for an answer of the second question before any edit:)

Comment: If you want an answer to the second question I would suggest you present the first part as background material and context, not as "a fun puzzle" (or "delightful exercise" or other flowery verbosity).  This is a Q&A site, and it is quite explicit about being that -- it tries to distinguish itself quite clearly from a forum for discussion.  I'm sorry if that sounds harsh but from the perspective of creating a repository of content to help answer-seekers, this is a not a well-written question :-/

Comment: @postmortes on the contrary thank you for the comments, but I will leave the question here for now in case anyone is writing an answer.

Comment: The question is nontrivial and certainly belongs here. It wouldn't on the other site. (And, for what it's worth, 
I don't think there are issues with the formulation of the question, I actually like how it is framed.)